# $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db_name=$db_name", $user, $pass);

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am faced this problem when installing a script. It gives me the following error:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dreads\recent\test\Feedstack-master\Feedstack-master\app\models\install.php
>   on line 35
>
> DB ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known.
>
> line 35 //$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db_name=$db_name", $user,
>   $pass);

any help!

```
defined('_PATHANG') or die;

class modelInstall{

    public function main($request){

            $db_name = $request->get('db_name');
            $host = $request->get('host');
            $user =$request->get('db_username');
            $pass = $request->get('db_password');


            $site_name = $request->get('site_name');
            $site_url = $request->Get('site_url');

            $this->create_db($db_name,$host,$user,$pass);
            $this->create_tables($db_name,$host,$user,$pass);
            $this->update_config($site_name,$site_url,$db_name,$host,$user,$pass);

    }

    public function create_db($db_name,$host,$user,$pass)
    {
            try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db_name=$db_name", $user, $pass);
                $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db_name`;") 
                or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
            }   
    }
```

Comment: _'No such host is known.'_ Whatever name you're providing as the MySQL server name, it's wrong.

Comment: i put localhost as a host and im using xampp!*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try connecting through MYSQLI

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: you mean instead of    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;db_name=$db_name", $user, $pass);

Comment: instead of using PDO
u can also use new mysqli for object oriented way

Comment: yes check this link for further information
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: thanks but it kinda lead me to an other error Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::exec() in

Comment: @HassanAlBourji the problem here is not PDO but missing or misspelled host name.

Answer (score 0):

Like Hobo Sapiens said, the host you are providing doesn't exists or is misspelled, i don't know the structure of your `$request` object. Your object structure needs to be something like the following.

```
class Request 
{
private $host;
private $db_name;
private $db_username;
private $db_pwd;

public function __construct($host,$db_name,$db_username,$db_pwd) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->db_name = $db_name;
    $this->db_username = $db_username;
    $this->db_pwd = $db_pwd;
}
public function getHost(){
    return $this->host;
}
public function getDBName(){
    return $this->db_name;
}
public function getDBUsername(){
    return $this->db_username;
}
public function getDBPwd(){
    return $this->db_pwd;
}
}
```

Then you can do something like the following

```
$request = new Request('localhost', 'TestingPDO', 'root', '');
$modelinstall = new modelInstall();
$modelinstall->main($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fix it

```
<?php

defined('_PATHANG') or die;
class modelInstall{
    public function main($request){
            $db_name = $request->get('db_name');
            $host = $request->get('host');
            $user =$request->get('db_username');
            $pass = $request->get('db_password');


            $site_name = $request->get('site_name');
            $site_url = $request->Get('site_url');
            $this->create_db($db_name,$host,$user,$pass);
            $this->create_tables($db_name,$host,$user,$pass);
            $this->update_config($site_name,$site_url,$db_name,$host,$user,$pass);
    }
    public function create_db($db_name,$host,$user,$pass)
    {
            try {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", 'root', 'mypassword');

                $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE `feedstack`;") 
                or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
            }   
    }
```