# PhpStorm XAMPP can't run php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting the following warning, when I attempt to run my `.php` classes on local host.

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\dbconnect.php
>   on line 8.

My other php classes works perfectly, but whenever `dbconnect.php` is included, it simply wont run.

Here's my `dbconnect.php` class:

```
 $DB_host = "XXX.dk.mysql";
 $DB_user = "XXX_dk_db_secure_login";
 $DB_pass = "XXX";
 $DB_name = "XXX_dk_db_secure_login";

 $MySQLi_CON = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);

 if($MySQLi_CON->connect_errno)
 {
     die("ERROR : -> ".$MySQLi_CON->connect_error);
 }
```

It works on my website (I can also create a user, log in and such ... so there shouldn't be anything wrong with my code).

I'm using XAMPP and everything show positive from the XAMPP Control Panel.

This is not a duplicate thread of [db-new-pdomysqlhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522924/db-new-pdomysqlhost-hostdb-name-db-name-user-pass)

Would could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname `$DB_host = "XXX.dk.mysql";` is referring to an external hostname which is not available on your local machine.
Probably you need to set this to either localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxx_dk_db_secure_login'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\dbconnect.php on line 10
ERROR : -> Access denied for user 'ademphotography_dk_db_secure_login'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


I get this error now.. I also tried using a blank password. 
What am I missing? :D It seems that I'm closer to a solution, thanks to you :)

Comment: I'am not sure what de default username and password is for XAMPP, but my guess it would be its username: `root` password is either empty or also `root` Also, please make sure you have the database `XXX_dk_db_secure_login ` restored in your local MySQL environment

Comment: Oh, wasn't so sure that I had to store it in my local MySQL environment... I'll try it out :)

Comment: I guess it's working. I just need to do a few tweaks here and there ... Now it just says " Unknown database " but that's probably just me not knowing how to peroperly set it up in my MySQL environment :D Thanks for the help.

Comment: it works now. Simply made a few syntaxt errors... I exported the sql from my phpadmin and pasted it into my MySQL workbench .. :D